# Anyway to Make Two Drawables for the Resolutions 854x480 and 800x480?

Tags: android, resolution

I am developing a game and for that I have two different layouts and images for 480x800 and 480x854 resolution images. Can anyone help me with the easiest way possible?

Comment: @kruti Don't ask question like these here, people are not here to do your work, please mention what steps you follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn little bit photoshop.
To change imagae size have a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQjDB9mbk3g).
And to change image resolution see this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1seG-hBN1Zc).

If you want to change resolution and size, make sure you'll do change from larger to smaller always not vice versa. Otherwise your image will be blured.